# How to create SPWeb in object model?

Tags: publishing-site

I will create my web and subwebs hierarchy from code. In past, in powershell i was using

> new-SPWeb -url $trimmed -template "BLANKINTERNET#0" -language 1055 -useparenttopnav -name $name1

What is the object model equivalent of that powershell command. I want to create web from URL. So the site.Webs.Add is no suitable for me,i want to setup the hierarchy from URL. So the code below is not OK for me.

```
site.Webs.Add(
    txtSiteName.Text,
    txtSiteName.Text,
    Convert.ToUInt32(1033),
    site.WebTemplate,
    false,
    false
    );
```

Comment: To be honest if you are running this locally, the object model is lacking in features for this and you are far better just calling stsadm for your needs, or even running the powershell from your code (Powershell is fully accessible) on a standard SharePoint installation.

Comment: what do you mean running locally? i am running this code on the sharepoint server

Comment: Do you want to run in it in page or in an application?

Comment: does not matter.but now i am on a console application

Comment: PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript("Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"); or call STSADM which is my preference for the same thing, from the app. A long time ago after weeks of trying to write all deployment types with the OM I found out it isn't the same, and a little incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest if you are running this locally, the object model is lacking in features for this and you are far better just calling stsadm for your needs, or even running the powershell from your code (Powershell is fully accessible) on a standard SharePoint installation.

so...

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript("Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell");
```

or call STSADM which is my preference for the same thing, from the app. A long time ago after weeks of trying to write all deployment types with the OM I found out it isn't the same, and a little incomplete.